# UWP How to detect pen button press

Tags: c#, uwp, event-handling, pen

I am developing an app in UWP for Windows 10.

I would like to perform some action when the user presses a button on the Pen (e.g. eraser or barrel button).

Ideally, I would like to have an app-wide listener that is fired when the user presses e.g. the eraser button, even when the pen is "far" from the screen (e.g. 30 cm / 1 foot distance between the pen and the screen).

Is there any way to achieve this in UWP / C#?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could check [the PenButtonListener Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.input.penbuttonlistener?view=winrt-19041) which is newly added in the build 19041.

Comment: I tried, but it is not working. It intermittently doesn't sense the click on the barrel button. Moreover, it works only for the Surface PC series. Have you tried it too?

Answer (score 0):

On latest windows 10, [Windows.Devices.Input.PenButtonListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.input.penbuttonlistener?view=winrt-19041) was added for this.

Comment: I tried, but it is not working. It intermittently doesn't sense the click on the barrel button. Moreover, it works only for the Surface PC series. Have you tried it too?